# jQuery ComboBox: Show & Hide?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, show-hide

Using jQuery ComboBox I have a Google Suggests and html dropdown like combination that beneath it I needs to show & hide information based on what is selected.

Within the dropdown I have US states and when one is selected I need to show it's corresponding city.  The cities are in the html code now set to display none.  Somehow I need to add display: block; when a user selects a state from the dropdown.  Can anyone share some insight on how this might be achieved?

Here is my code

```js
 (function($) {
   $.widget("custom.combobox", {
     _create: function() {
       this.wrapper = $("<span>")
         .addClass("custom-combobox")
         .insertAfter(this.element);

       this.element.hide();
       this._createAutocomplete();
       this._createShowAllButton();
     },

     _createAutocomplete: function() {
       var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
         value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

       this.input = $("<input>")
         .appendTo(this.wrapper)
         .val(value)
         .attr("title", "")
         .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
         .autocomplete({
           delay: 0,
           minLength: 0,
           source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
         })
         .tooltip({
           tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
         });

       this._on(this.input, {
         autocompleteselect: function(event, ui) {
           ui.item.option.selected = true;
           this._trigger("select", event, {
             item: ui.item.option
           });
         },

         autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
       });
     },

     _createShowAllButton: function() {
       var input = this.input,
         wasOpen = false;

       $("<a>")
         .attr("tabIndex", -1)
         .attr("title", "Show All Items")
         .tooltip()
         .appendTo(this.wrapper)
         .button({
           icons: {
             primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
           },
           text: false
         })
         .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
         .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
         .mousedown(function() {
           wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
         })
         .click(function() {
           input.focus();

           // Close if already visible
           if (wasOpen) {
             return;
           }

           // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
           input.autocomplete("search", "");
         });
     },

     _source: function(request, response) {
       var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
       response(this.element.children("option").map(function() {
         var text = $(this).text();
         if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
           return {
             label: text,
             value: text,
             option: this
           };
       }));
     },

     _removeIfInvalid: function(event, ui) {

       // Selected an item, nothing to do
       if (ui.item) {
         return;
       }

       // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
       var value = this.input.val(),
         valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
         valid = false;
       this.element.children("option").each(function() {
         if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
           this.selected = valid = true;
           return false;
         }
       });

       // Found a match, nothing to do
       if (valid) {
         return;
       }

       // Remove invalid value
       this.input
         .val("")
         .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
         .tooltip("open");
       this.element.val("");
       this._delay(function() {
         this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
       }, 2500);
       this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
     },

     _destroy: function() {
       this.wrapper.remove();
       this.element.show();
     }
   });
 })(jQuery);

 $(function() {
   $("#combobox").combobox();
   $("#toggle").click(function() {
     $("#combobox").toggle();
   });
 });

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.box').hide();
   $('#ui-id-1').change(function() {
     $('.box').show();
   });
 });
```

```css
 *:focus {
   outline: 0;
 }
 .custom-combobox {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .custom-combobox-toggle {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin-left: -1px;
   padding: 0;
   border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
   background-color: #E0E0E0;
 }
 .custom-combobox-input {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
   width: 88%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ui-widget">
  <select id="combobox" name="combobox">
    <option value="0">Find your state</option>
    <option value="1">Alabama</option>
    <option value="2">Alaska</option>-->
    <option value="3">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="4">Arizona</option>
    <option value="5">California</option>
    <option value="6">Colorado</option>
    <option value="7">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="8">Delaware</option>
    <option value="9">Florida</option>
    <option value="10">Georgia</option>
    <option value="11">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="12">Idaho</option>
    <option value="13">Illinois</option>
    <option value="14">Indiana</option>
    <option value="15">Iowa</option>
    <option value="16">Kansas</option>
    <option value="17">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="18">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="19">Maine</option>
    <option value="20">Maryland</option>
    <option value="21">Massachusetts</option>
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li id="1" class="box">
      Birmingham
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="box">
      Juneau
    </li>
    <li id="3" class="box">
      Little Rock
    </li>
    <li id="4" class="box">
      Flagstaff
    </li>
    <li id="5" class="box">
      Sacremento
    </li>
    <li id="6" class="box">
      Denver
    </li>
    <li id="7" class="box">
      Hartford
    </li>
    <li id="8" class="box">
      Dover
    </li>
    <li id="9" class="box">
      Orlando
    </li>
    <li id="10" class="box">
      Atlanta
    </li>
    <li id="11" class="box">
      Honolulu
    </li>
    <li id="12" class="box">
      Boise
    </li>
    <li id="13" class="box">
      Chicago
    </li>
    <li id="14" class="box">
      Indianapolis
    </li>
    <li id="15" class="box">
      Cedar Rapids
    </li>
    <li id="16" class="box">
      Kansas City
    </li>
    <li id="17" class="box">
      Louisville
    </li>
    <li id="18" class="box">
      New Orleans
    </li>

    <li id="19" class="box">
      Austuga
    </li>

    <li id="20" class="box">
      Annapolis
    </li>

    <li id="21" class="box">
      Boston
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Not sure that snippet is working properly, but it my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/do3bv9so/) is functional.

Comment: How are you mapping State to city?

Comment: When you inspect the element you see the combo box's code generates the actual dropdown list via the <ul id="ui-id-1"> and within it are the states each within it's own <  li  >.  Each < li >  has it's own unique id .. like id="ui-id-4" , id="ui-id-5," and etc .. yet each time you click the dropdown the unique id numbers change by an increase of 19.  The states just have static numeric ids like <li id="1">,<li id="2"> and so on.  The fact that the jQuery UI code forces the ui-id- numbers to dynamically change each time the dropdown is clicked is what is tripping me up here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are mapping state to city but what you could do is as below.

```
    this._on( this.input, {
                autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
                    alert(ui.item.option.value);
                    $('.box').toggle();
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    this._trigger( "select", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option

                    });
                },

                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
```

With in `autocompleteselect` you can `toggle()` also you can get the value of selected option with `ui.item.option.value`. You need to handle for invalid values. You could do that within `_removeIfInvalid` function declaration.

I would recommend defining state to city mapping in JSON file with key as value of state option and values as city list. Keeping city list empty/no list at all. Based on values selected you could read JSON file to create dynamic list and append it to div.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by using JSON and the solution can be seen in [here](http://goo.gl/2kEWRv) in a fiddle.

On a separate note to Stackoverflow if you want to post this code/content/solution of mine here go ahead and post it, but I have no interest in doing double work.  Bad UI/UX and subjectively it's only being done for the better of S.O. (increase content & keep users on SO) not the user.

Comment: add `$("#city-list").empty();` to `_removeIfInvalid` function if user clears input in combobox to empty.